# Exception logged in Rivr VoiceXML but no malfunction

Tags: voicexml, rivr

I am getting the exception logged in my Rivr apps when Dialog ends (user hang-up for example)
I am not really getting any problems but the log gets a lot of them. Is there any way to handle/address/stop them?

(Using WAS Liberty Profile 8.5.5.7)

Thanks

```
[10/7/15 20:28:30:396 UTC] 00009c81 org.jboss.weld.Servlet                                       W WELD-000712: Unable to dissociate context org.jboss.weld.context.http.LazyHttpConversationContextImpl@f6571a54 from the storage com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.srt.SRTServletRequest31@342e6aa
[10/7/15 20:28:30:447 UTC] 00009ca3 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.util.ApplicationErrorUtils           E SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.ibm.ws.session.http.HttpSessionImpl.getAttributeNames:225'
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.ibm.ws.session.http.HttpSessionImpl.getAttributeNames(HttpSessionImpl.java:225)
    at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionData.getAttributeNames(SessionData.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.session.HttpSessionFacade.getAttributeNames(HttpSessionFacade.java:152)
    at com.nuecho.rivr.core.servlet.session.Session.keepAlive(Session.java:76)
    at com.nuecho.rivr.core.servlet.session.SessionContainer.getSession(SessionContainer.java:120)
    at com.nuecho.rivr.core.servlet.DialogueServlet.getExistingSession(DialogueServlet.java:510)
    at com.nuecho.rivr.core.servlet.DialogueServlet.getSession(DialogueServlet.java:495)
    at com.nuecho.rivr.core.servlet.DialogueServlet.process(DialogueServlet.java:376)
    at com.nuecho.rivr.core.servlet.DialogueServlet.doPost(DialogueServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1287)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:146)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:78)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1020)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1142)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4867)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31.handleRequest(WebApp31.java:523)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:997)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:341)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:470)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:404)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:284)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What is your session timeout in your web.xml?

Comment: Hello Gawi, in this project it was not specified. We usually set it to 30 mins. I'll set it to that value. Should it make any change in the issue? Thanks.

Comment: The only reason I can think why you are having this error is that the session timeout is too short.  I guess that the time between the last VoiceXML document is being generated by Rivr and the user is hanging up is greater that the session time-out.  It would be an explanation.